# Is it possible to extract and visualize voice data using Python?

Tags: python, signal-processing

I want to implement two things using `Python 3.5`

1. I want to extract voice of each actor or actress from the movie or drama file(`mp4,mkv` or `mp3` file). I want to save this extracted voice as a `mp3` file.
2. Using above data, I see the data of my voice (Either time domain or frequency domain doesn't matter)

Do both of them can be implemented using Python?

Comment: You again!  This question is also at risk for being closed because it isn’t asking a [coding question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Here’s some thoughts though. (1) Do you have some kind of metadata to tell you when a specific actor or actress is speaking (subtitle file, or even hand-annotated start/stop times)? If so, many tools including ffmpeg can extract audio. If *not*, this is the [speaker diarization problem](http://multimedia.icsi.berkeley.edu/speaker-diarization/) which is a big research topic in signal processing/machine learning.

Comment: (2) Yes, look at [scipy.signal.spectrogram](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.spectrogram.html) to use the short-time Fourier transform (STFT) to visualize the frequency content as it changes over time.